# conf/reference.conf doesn't work in dist zip in Play 2.2.1 with Akka 2.2.3

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm coding [P2P application](https://github.com/Windymelt/p2p2ch) in Scala which works on Play 2.2.1 with Akka 2.2.3.
When I dist my Play project, `my project/conf/reference.conf` will be included in dist zip. This is okay.

Next, I extracted the ZIP and overwrote `conf/reference.conf` in order to test for localizing for user environment.
However, my application doesn't work using configuration of reference.conf; It still use default settings. (Akka using default settings.)

For example, 
conf/reference.conf:

```
p2pakka.akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname="foobar.local"
p2pakka.akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=44444
```

Actual behavior:

```
p2pakka.akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname="127.0.0.1"
p2pakka.akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=22223
```

In my code:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
val customConf = config.getConfig("p2pakka").withFallback({
    println("fallbacking");
    config
})
val system = ActorSystem("foobar", ConfigFactory.load(customConf))
// still using default settings.
```

As far as using `play run`, `conf/reference.conf` exactly works as I wrote.

Are there any wrong with my code? Is `conf/reference.conf` in zip invalid?

I'd like to know how to applying change in `conf/reference.conf` by user, after `dist`ed by developer. I googled about this problem, but I couldn't find out any answer.

---

I'm not native English speaker, so please forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, Play includes a copy of the config file inside the jar it generates.

If you use

```
-Dconfig.file=/path/to/prod.conf &
```

as a command line param (updated path for your env) when starting it should pick up the changes